# Accessing superclass members from subclass with super keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I have a subclass and a superclass. In the subclass when I want to retrieve the values of the super class with `super.i` and `super.one` it shows zero - why?

Also, when I extend a superclass, is it necessary to call the superclass method using the `super` keyword?

```java
public class Inherit {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello Inheritance!");
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(now);
        Box hello = new Box(2, 3, 4);
        BoxWeight hello_weight = new BoxWeight(2, 5, 4, 5);
        hello.volume();
        hello_weight.volume();
        Box hello_old = hello;
        hello = hello_weight;
        //hello.showValues();
        hello.show();
        hello_old.show();
        hello = hello_old;
        hello.show();
        hello.setValues(7, 8);
        hello_weight.setValues(70, 80);
        hello.showValues();
        hello_weight.showValues();
    }
}

class Box {
    int width, height, depth, i, one;
    static int as = 0;

    Box(int w, int h, int d) {
        ++as;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        depth = d;
    }

    void setValues(int a, int k) {
        i = k;
        one = a;
        System.out.println("The values inside super are : " + i + " " + one + " " + as);
    }

    void showValues() {
        System.out.println("The values of BoxWeight : " + i + " " + one);
        //System.out.println("The superclass values : "+ super.i + " " + super.one);
    }

    void volume() {
        System.out.println("Volume : " + width * height * depth);
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("The height : " + height);
    }
}

class BoxWeight extends Box {
    int weight, i, one;

    void volume() {
        System.out.println("Volume and weight : " + width * height * depth + " " + weight);
    }

    void setValues(int a, int k) {
        i = k;
        one = a;
    }

    void showValues() {
        System.out.println("The values of BoxWeight : " + i + " " + one);
        System.out.println("The superclass values : " + super.i + " " + super.one);
    }

    BoxWeight(int w, int h, int d, int we) {
        super(w, h, d);
        weight = we;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you have not initialized one, so by default it gets value as zero.

```
hello_weight
```

is object of Box_Weight class, and when you call setValues of that class, **one** of this class is initailized, and super class one is **shadowed**. So super class **one** is still zero.

And **one** is not initialized in constructor.

Comment: I think I have initialised the values using the constructor.

Comment: How do I access the super class values then??

Comment: either change field name in sub class, or initialize with super.one, anything will work.

Comment: moreover, its a bad practice to use field directly in any other class, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `super` keyword to access members of the parent class. What you do need, however, is to have proper scope / visibility.

If your parent class has fields that are `protected` as opposed to `private`, then only members of the subclass can see them.

Answer (score 0):

Default scope of a variable is *package private*. If you want to access the parent class variables, make them `protected` or place child and parent both in same packages.

In your case the `int width, height, depth, i, one;` variables are package private. So, if your subclass is not inside the same package as the superclass, then it can't access them. Hence declare them as `protected`.